# Thermistor with sharp "cutoff" edge (reaching around 45°C)?

Tags: temperature, thermistor, ptc

Is there a thermistor which has a very low resistance up to about 45°C and then, within a few degrees, raises the resistance to a very high resistance? Sort of like a self resetting thermal cutoff fuse, but with a raising resistance before cutoff.

Comment: Better to use a thermistor in a bridge with gain to drive FET

Comment: Why do you use a regular thermistor and a comparator with the switching voltage of the comparator set to the thermistors...

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like a [polyfuse](https://www.littelfuse.com/products/polyswitch-resettable-ptcs.aspx)?

[image]

Comment: Pretty much exactly like those, but are they somehow bound to "overcurrent-creates-temperature" (from what I've read so far, they are) or do they also react to outside temperature?

Comment: Also consider a bimetallic thermal switch. Those are readily available in NC and NO configurations around that temperature.

Comment: PTC’ polyfuses are usually >=85’C but there are many variations

Answer (score 1):

yes you will need to check out the PRF series from Murata, PTC thermistors for that type of characteristic.